# XLabs WebView giving Error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: android, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I'm trying to get the Sample Project

> XLabs.Sample.Droid

running on my machine but it gives me the error

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

on the following line in MainActivity.OnCreate():

```
Android.Webkit.WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

The error is thrown somewhere inside the WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled Code. What can I do?

Comment: Can you add the full Exception log after "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Comment: @Luis: This message is the full Exception Log. That's my problem, I have now idea where the exception is coming from...

Comment: Some more Info: If I don't set a breabpoint before this line and just start the App I just get the error: Unhandled exception occured. Without further informations. If I comment this line most of the samples work but I get the same error at a later time using the HybridWebView at a random point... or the app is just crashing without a message after a random number of clicks...

Comment: Please read XLabs Wiki, maybe it helps: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki, particularly the "Important information for those who have used Xamarin.Forms.Labs" section, as it mentions that a refactoring is in process and 1.2.x based projects will break.

Comment: I'm reading it alread. But I'm completely new to Xamarin. I installed it three days ago and the problems I have are happening on the freshly downloaded unchanged GitHub Sample Project. I'm not upgrading old code. I have commented the two GetWebViewClient(Chrome)Delegate calls and commented the line above and it looks a lot better now. Still it would be great to activate WebContentDebugging...